# Install Kite plugin in GitHub's Atom Editor

Tags: text, installation, atom-editor

I would like to try [Kite](https://www.kite.com/), which is concept of artificial intelligence helping developers with hints about useful functions or expressions that he or she is currently writing.  I have downloaded the [Kite Atom plugin](https://github.com/kiteco/plugins) from GitHub.

However, as I am new to GitHub's Atom Editor I don't know how to install this plugin into editor.

Comment: How did you get on @jenism, did you managed to get the kite package installed in Atom.

Comment: hi, thx for help..the installation was succesfull! But how do i start kite now? is it started defaultly with atom? i would like to see all the hints and documentation help that kite provides :)

Comment: Atom plugins are enabled by default, you will need to [sign up for Kite](https://www.kite.com/) to be able to use the full experience.

Comment: yes i have signed up and i am waiting for invitation now. is there any clue about when i will get the invitation?

Comment: I'd never heard of `kite` until you mentioned it, I have signed up to get access to the beta myself but only in the last couple of hours.

Comment: ok i will let u know if i get the beta invitation access and how it works

Comment: Thank you, you can always find me on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this plugin isn't available from the Atom Package Manager repository you will need to link this manually:

1. Clone the Repository.
2. Change to the `plugins\atom` directory.
3. Run the following command:

   ```
   apm link kite
   ```

I've created a short animation to show you me doing this on my system:

[image: Screenshot installing Kite]

Comment: may you please tell how to do it on sublime-text

Comment: @NourAlhadiMahmoud I'm afraid I don't know how to do it in Sublime Text 2/3 - can I suggest posting a new question? Alternatively maybe get in contact with Kite for support.

Comment: Much as I appreciate a thorough answer, a gif of terminal commands absent the corresponding text isn't very useful.

Comment: The directory `plugins/atom` does not exist in the repository you reference. The top level can be viewed [here](https://github.com/kiteco/plugins).