# Install Kite plugin in Portable Sublime Text 3

Tags: ide, sublimetext3, sublimetext, kite

My question is essentially a copy of ([Install Kite plugin in GitHub's Atom Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802125/install-kite-plugin-in-githubs-atom-editor)) for Sublime Text 3, specifically the portable no-install version (I'm on Windows 10, but this possibly applies cross platform).

How do I install the plugin for this please?

I tried the "Add Repository" option in Sublime Text 3, with URL: https://github.com/kiteco/plugins

but this doesn't seem to have added any functionality or add Kite to my package list.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

open Preferences>Package Settings>Kite> Sublime Kite Settings - User

add

"expand_panel_on_select": true

That enabled the context dialog for me when I clicked on an import or def.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Demonstration

I successful install Kite to my portable Sublime Text on disk `D:\`.

[image: Kite tour]

[image: Kite in command palette]

---

### 2. Relevancy

This answer relevance at February 2018. I hope, that soon Kite plugin would be possible install simply as another Sublime Text plugins and this answer will be obsolete.

---

### 3. Installation

1. Download and install Kite service from [**home Page of Kite site**](https://kite.com/).
2. Run installed Kite. You need always run Kite service, when you use Kite.
3. Download Kite Sublime Text plugin from [**here**](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/kite-plugin-binaries/latest/Kite.sublime-package).
4. Place `Kite.sublime-package` archive to `<path_to_your_Sublime_Text_folder>\Data\Installed Packages`. For example, I add `Kite.sublime-package` to `D:\Sublime Text 3 x64\Data\Installed Packages` folder.
5. If you use Anaconda or any conflicted plugins, Kite will prompt you to change your settings.

---

### 4. Read more

- [**“Custom Windows installation section” in “Managing editor integrations” article**](http://help.kite.com/article/62-managing-editor-integrations).

---

### 5. Testing environment

- Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN,
- Sublime Text Build 3143 portable on disk `D:\`,
- Kite 1.2018.124.0,
- Sublime Text Kite plugin from **https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/kite-plugin-binaries/latest/Kite.sublime-package** source.

Answer (score 0):

The structure they use is not natively supported by Sublime Text, because it does not load plugins from subfolders. However you can

1. Clone/download the repository.
2. In Sublime Text select *Preferences > Browse Packages...*. This should open a folder.
3. In that folder create a subfolder `Kite` and copy the files from the kite [`sublime-text`](https://github.com/kiteco/plugins/tree/master/sublime-text) folder into it.
   As an alternative you can also create a symlink.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to work I'm afraid. When I click Preferences -> Settings, it opens the settings file (although I can work out the folder location from this). However, when cloning and exporting the sublime-text folder from the Kite repo to this folder, there is no change in Sublime. Kite is not listed in the packages, nor is any functionality available. Did this work for you with Kite and Sublime Text 3 please?

Comment: @SLater01 Sorry you need to click Preferences > Browse Packages... . I corrected it. At the end the folder structure should be `<...>/Packages/Kite/SublimeKite.py`. I don't use Kite, but SublimeKite.py is a Sublime Text plugin and they must be placed in a subfolder of Packages to be loaded into Sublime Text.
You can also open the console ``ctrl+` `` and look, which packages and plugins are loaded on startup. If SublimeKite.py is one of them I cannot assist you anymore and you should create an issue at github.
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I've checked that Kite is loaded but adds no discernible functionality, so it must be an issue with the plugin. I'll try and contact the Kite devs to see if they have a solution. Thanks r-stein for clarifying ST3 package imports.

Comment: You also need to start the Kite program, because it provides a server, which is used by the ST plugin.

Comment: Ok, I did run the Kite installer and can see that it's active in my taskbar... so I think the server is running, although I still don't see any added functionality. I'd be intrigued to know if anyone else has managed to get this working? Cheers.

Comment: didn't work for me either. Console shows kite.sublimeKite loaded

Answer (score 0):

4 years later:

Clone the repo [`https://github.com/kiteco/KiteSublime`](https://github.com/kiteco/KiteSublime) or download and extract the latest [KiteSublime](https://github.com/kiteco/KiteSublime/archive/master.zip)

to

```
DRIVE:\[Sublime Path]\Data\Packages
```

That's it.